# Combine update with select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a column in a table based on the results returned from a select statement. Not sure how to combine the two. Basically want to update IsActive column to one in the MemberInstanceInfo table for the results that get returned in the SELECT statement. Im doing this in SQL Server.

```
update xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo
Set IsActive = 1

SELECT MIN(M.GICMembID) AS GICMembID, M.LastName, M.FirstName, M.FullName, M.Date_Birth, CP.CaseNum, CP.CaseNumber 
FROM xG_v341_GICD.dbo.tCD_MemberInfo M
      INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT LastName, FirstName, CONVERT(varchar(10), Date_Birth, 112) AS DOB, COUNT(*) AS Ct
                        FROM xG_v341_GICD.[dbo].tCD_MemberInfo
                        GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Date_Birth
                        HAVING count(*)>1
                        )  G
            ON M.LastName = G.LastName
            AND M.FirstName = G.FirstName
            AND M.Date_Birth = G.DOB
      LEFT JOIN xG_v341_GIWeb.dbo.tCM_CarePlan CP
            ON M.GICMembID = CP.GICMembID
      JOIN xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo MII
            ON M.HP_Memb_UniqueID = MII.HP_Memb_UniqueID
WHERE CP.GICMembID IS NULL
GROUP BY M.LastName, M.FirstName, M.FullName, M.Date_Birth, CP.CaseNum, CP.CaseNumber
ORDER BY M.LastName, M.FirstName
```

Comment: You can do an update from. Unfortunately it is not at all clear what you want to do here.

Comment: UPDATE table_alias SET values FROM your_query

Comment: Are all those fields in your `SELECT` required to uniquely identify a record in the `tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo` table?

Comment: I tried that but get an error about the Group by portion of the statement. The result returns a list of names that I can link to the MemberInstanceInfo table by an ID. I need to set the IsActive column for each ID to 1.

Comment: GICMembID, firstname, lastname, and DOB are really what is needed to identify the unique record.

Comment: Does xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo have all the key columns - GICMembID, firstname, lastname, and DOB

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm seeing, and assuming that `GICMembID` is the reference value between the two sets, this is how I would approach it.

Setup a CTE (`ActiveMembers`) which returns only the records you want to "activate".  Since the update only needs `GICMembID`, you can/should remove the rest of the values from the select inside the CTE.  Once the CTE is returning the proper results, join that back to `tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo` and convert to an update.

```
;WITH ActiveMembers 
AS 
(
SELECT MIN(M.GICMembID) AS GICMembID, M.LastName, M.FirstName, M.FullName, M.Date_Birth, CP.CaseNum, CP.CaseNumber 
FROM xG_v341_GICD.dbo.tCD_MemberInfo M
      INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT LastName, FirstName, CONVERT(varchar(10), Date_Birth, 112) AS DOB, COUNT(*) AS Ct
                        FROM xG_v341_GICD.[dbo].tCD_MemberInfo
                        GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Date_Birth
                        HAVING count(*)>1
                        )  G
            ON M.LastName = G.LastName
            AND M.FirstName = G.FirstName
            AND M.Date_Birth = G.DOB
      LEFT JOIN xG_v341_GIWeb.dbo.tCM_CarePlan CP
            ON M.GICMembID = CP.GICMembID
      JOIN xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo MII
            ON M.HP_Memb_UniqueID = MII.HP_Memb_UniqueID
WHERE CP.GICMembID IS NULL
GROUP BY M.LastName, M.FirstName, M.FullName, M.Date_Birth, CP.CaseNum, CP.CaseNumber
ORDER BY M.LastName, M.FirstName
)

SELECT *
--update T Set IsActive = 1
FROM xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo T
JOIN ActiveMembers A 
   ON T.GICMembID = A.GICMembID
```

Run this as a select, and if it is returning the correct result set, you can switch to an update (commented out).

If you need to you can add `AND T.firstname=A.firstname` etc if required to match up to the `tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo` table correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax for an update with a `JOIN` is:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.col1 = b.col1
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
    ON a.col1 = b.colx
WHERE --optional criteria
```

This should work for your case:

```
UPDATE  a
SET a.IsActive = 1
FROM xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo a
JOIN (  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY M.LastName, M.FirstName, M.FullName, M.Date_Birth, CP.CaseNum, CP.CaseNumber  ORDER BY  M.GICMembID) RN
        FROM xG_v341_GICD.dbo.tCD_MemberInfo M
                INNER JOIN (
                                SELECT LastName, FirstName, CONVERT(varchar(10), Date_Birth, 112) AS DOB, COUNT(*) AS Ct
                                FROM xG_v341_GICD.[dbo].tCD_MemberInfo
                                GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Date_Birth
                                HAVING count(*)>1
                                )  G
                    ON M.LastName = G.LastName
                    AND M.FirstName = G.FirstName
                    AND M.Date_Birth = G.DOB
                LEFT JOIN xG_v341_GIWeb.dbo.tCM_CarePlan CP
                    ON M.GICMembID = CP.GICMembID
                JOIN xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo MII
                    ON M.HP_Memb_UniqueID = MII.HP_Memb_UniqueID
        WHERE CP.GICMembID IS NULL
      ) b
ON a.GICMembID = b.GICMembID
 AND a.Firstname = b.Firstname
 AND a.lastname = b.lastname
 AND a.DOB = b.DOB
WHERE RN = 1
```

The whole thing could likely be refactored, but it's hard to sift through without additional familiarity.  I switched from `MIN()` to `ROW_NUMBER()` so that I could return all fields needed to `JOIN` without requiring an additional subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional info about the schema, this is the best I could come up with. Run the select query to verify before doing the update.

```
SELECT UpdateTable.*
--UPDATE UpdateTable SET isActive = 1
FROM 
(SELECT MIN(M.GICMembID) AS GICMembID, M.LastName, M.FirstName, M.FullName, M.Date_Birth, CP.CaseNum, CP.CaseNumber 
FROM xG_v341_GICD.dbo.tCD_MemberInfo M
  INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT LastName, FirstName, CONVERT(varchar(10), Date_Birth, 112) AS DOB, COUNT(*) AS Ct
                    FROM xG_v341_GICD.[dbo].tCD_MemberInfo
                    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Date_Birth
                    HAVING count(*)>1
                    )  G
        ON M.LastName = G.LastName
        AND M.FirstName = G.FirstName
        AND M.Date_Birth = G.DOB
  LEFT JOIN xG_v341_GIWeb.dbo.tCM_CarePlan CP
        ON M.GICMembID = CP.GICMembID
  JOIN xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo MII
        ON M.HP_Memb_UniqueID = MII.HP_Memb_UniqueID
WHERE CP.GICMembID IS NULL
GROUP BY M.LastName, M.FirstName, M.FullName, M.Date_Birth, CP.CaseNum, CP.CaseNumber)   AggTable
INNER JOIN xG_v341_GICD.dbo.tCD_MemberInfo LookupupTable on 
  LookupupTable.GICMembID = AggTable.GICMembID AND LookupupTable.LastName =   AggTable.LastName AND  LookupupTable.FirstName = AggTable.FirstName AND LookupupTable.Date_Birth = AggTable.Date_Birth
INNER JOIN xG_v341_GISync.dbo.tSTG_MemberInstanceInfo UpdateTable ON LookupupTable.HP_Memb_UniqueID = UpdateTable.HP_Memb_UniqueID
```